# Django djdt_flamegtaph blank?

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7xIx.png)

Django djdt_flamegtaph blank?

```
Django                    4.2.7
django-debug-toolbar      4.2.0
djdt-flamegraph           0.2.13
```

Dear friend, why is the page empty? Use python3 manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading to start django

Comment: Are you using macos?

Comment: Yes, this is running on a mac air computer